# Testing a react component value that relies on api promises and state setting to have completed

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have the following react page (simplified) which is basically a form- the default values of the form are loaded from an API call. the code that makes this API call and loads the values happens when the `someDep` context changes or if the reset button is pressed.

```
import {useContext, useState} from "react";
import {someDepContext} from "../src/SomeDepContext";
import {ApiFunctions} from "../src/ApiFunctions";
import {customUseEffect, Environment, ApiService} from "../src/CustomUseEffect";
import {Input} from "../src/Components/Input";
import {Button} from "../src/Components/Button";
import {LoadingComponent} from "../src/Components/Loading";

export default function MainForm() {
    const {someDep} = useContext(someDepContext);
    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({})
    const [pageStatus, setPageStatus] = useState({});
    const [apiFunctions, setApiFunctions] = useState<ApiFunctions>()

    customUseEffect((e: Environment, api: ApiService): void => {
        const apiFns = new ApiFunctions(e, api)
        setApiFunctions(apiFns);
        loadValues();
    }, [someDep])

    const loadValues = (): void => {
        if (!someDep) return

        setPageStatus({...pageStatus, IsLoading: true});
        apiFunctions?.getValuesFromAPI(someDep.SomeValue).then((apiValues: any) => {
            setFormValues(apiValues);
            setPageStatus({...pageStatus, IsLoading: false});
        });
    }

    if (pageStatus.IsLoading) return <LoadingComponent/>

    return (
        <>
            <Button
                data-testid="reset-btn"
                onClick={() => loadValues()} />
            <Input
                value={formValues.InputId}
                data-testid="input-id"
                readonly />
        </>
    )
}
```

this page works fine, the issue comes when trying to test it and mock the API call, I wrote a simple test to check that the value of the input loads correctly:

```
export const mockValues = {
    InputId: "Test Input Id",
}


describe("VendorConfigMain", () => {
    const someDep = {SomeValue: "test"};

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.spyOn(global.React, "useContext").mockImplementation(() => ({someDep} as any));
        jest.spyOn(ApiFunctions.prototype, "getValuesFromAPI").mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(mockValues));
    });

    it("populate input field", async () => {
        render(<MainForm />);

        await waitFor(() => {
            expect(screen.queryByTestId("loading-screen")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
        });

        // Now check for the platform ID input value
        const input = screen.getByTestId("input-id");
        expect(input.textContent).toBe(`${mockValues.InputId}`);
    });
});
```

however due to I assume my own misunderstanding of how the mockImplementation works, the code inside the `then()` block from `getValuesFromAPI` never runs, the loading screen never vanishes and so the test fails because it can't get the input element. I have a feeling that it might be something to do with storing the `ApiFunctions` in state, and either that means the test library doesn't wait for the state to have set or the mock fails because I am not accessing the `ApuFunctions.prototype` directly. My searching lead me to beleive that the `await waitFor()` block should wait for the loading screen to disappear and it should "just work" but that doesn't seem to be the case